# Prove that exists such sequence....

Tags: combinatorics

Given is a set of number: $$ {a_1, ... , a_{11} } $$
Prove that there exists a sequence of non-zero, that $$ x_1, ..., x_ {11} $$ of words from the set {1,0,1} that the number of:
$$ x_1a_1 + ... + x_{11} a_ {11}  $$ is divisible by 11.

Comment: What do you mean by the set $\{1,0,1\}$? How is that different from the set $\{0,1\}$?

Comment: Why can't you just take $x_1=x_2=\dots=x_{11}=0$?

Comment: Do you mean there exists 11 numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_{11}$ taking values from $\{ -1, 0, 1 \}$, not all of them are zero such that...

Comment: @achillehui Maybe that's what he/she means, but in that case there's no need for $-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s_k=a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k$ for $k=0,1,2,\dots,11$. By the Pigeonhole Principle there are indices $m,n$ such that $0\le m\lt n\le11$ and $s_m\equiv s_n\pmod{11}$. If we take $x_i=1$ for $m\lt i\le n$ and $x_i=0$ otherwise, then $a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\cdots+a_{11}x_{11}$ is divisible by $11$. Is that what you meant?

Comment: +1 independent whether this is what the OP asks, this desires an upvote.